# HTML/JS Bootstrap Datetimepicker change format base on js event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am working with the datetimepicker using bootstrap, it is okie for me to create the datetimepicker with difference format

```
startPicker = $('#datetimepickerstart').datetimepicker({
    format: time_format,
    language: 'en'
});
```

time_format is valid string for the datetime format.
But, my question: Is there any way to change that format after the datetimepicker initialized.
For example. I have radiobutton to change the format, once the radiobutton clicked, I need to change format correctly.
I have tried:

```
$('#range_include_time_option .btn-small').click(function () {        
    if ($(this).attr("value") == 'range_dateonly') {
        startPicker.format = 'yyy-MM-dd';
    } else {
        startPicker.format = 'yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss';
    }
});
```

But the datetimepicker still be the same as it is initialized.
I also have tried with

```
if ($(this).attr("value") == 'range_dateonly') {
    $('#datetimepickerstart').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        language: 'en'
    });
} else {
    $('#datetimepickerstart').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'en'
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Please help me, is this a existing problem with the bootstrap datetimepicker or some thing wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found a sily solution, I have droped all the datetimepicker and create newone, just remain the id of the text box for reference later.
BTQ, As I said, the solution is stupid, I am very appreciated with better solution.